# Make query run faster - IT HAS NO JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I got a really huge amount of data that are used to be joined anywhere just to get it (because it was really slow the team decided to gather it all into one table), but now even though they're literally right in one table (no join needed).

It's still so slow. Taking a one day range filter event will lead to time out (took more than 10s, yes that's how bad it is).

What should I suggest to my DBA?

Comment: *cough* Indexing *cough*

Comment: And query optimization to avoid full table scans if possible.

Comment: In fact your DBA should suggest things to you (if he is worth his pay).

Comment: What are you filtering? if you are searching for? Text in one of the columns or something?

Comment: `What should I suggest to my DBA?` plus `... the team decided to gather it all into one table` Tell your DBA to ignore the team, and DONT DENORMALIZE, instead he should create/maintain the correct key/indexing structure.

Comment: Hi! This question is a bit too broad for the format of this site, because it is likely to lead to a series of back and forth suggestions and discussions of possible strategies, whereas this site is designed to be strictly Question and Answer. Try to make the question more specific - give us details of your schema (what columns does this one table have?), the kind of data in it (how big is "huge"?), the query you're trying to run. Note also that there's [a sister site dedicated to database administration](https://dba.stackexchange.com), where a suitably specific question might be welcome.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

What is the "selectivity"? That is, how many rows does your select expect to retrieve? 100% of the rows? 1% of the rows? 0.01% of the rows?

**1. Low selectivity**

If the selectivity is low (i.e less than 5%, ideally less than 0.5%) then good indexing is the best practice.

If so, which columns in the where clause (filtering columns) have the best (lowest) selectivity? Add these columns first in the index.

Once you have decided on the best index, you can make the table a "clustered index" table using that index. That way the heap will be presorted (fast lookup) by the index columns, for improved io since the disk blocks will be looked up sequentially.

**2. High selectivity**

If the selectivity is high (20% or more), there's no much you can do on your side (development). You could still get some improvement by:

- Removing unneeded columns.
- Make sure the select uses a FULL TABLE SCAN.
- Ask the DBA to assign more resources (SGA, disk priority, paralellism, etc.)

**3. Otherwise**

The amount of data you have vastly exceeds the database resources you have. There's nothing you can do about it, except to tell the client about this reality, and:

- Find together a way of defining smaller queries that can be achievable.

**4. Finally**

If you don't understanf the terms of selectivity, full table scan, indexing, database resources, heap, disk blocks, I would recommend you study them. I'm fairly sure you need to fully understand them right now!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need an index. However if it's *really* huge you can partition the data.

This allows you to drop sections of the data without using time consuming deletes. For example if you're working with some sort of historical data and want to keep 3 months worth, you can partition by month, then each month drop the oldest partition.

However on a more general note, it's rarely a good idea to take a slow multi-table query and glom it all together to improve performance. What you really need is to figure out what's wrong with the slow query and fix it.

This is a job for your DBA.